# Use AndroidX And Support Lib Together?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

Migrate to Androidx, use Jetifier, I know that, but Jetifier can't resolve my problem!
I have a lib use support library, and it's shared by many apps, so it's impossible to migrate to androidx. but I use androidx in application module, the problem is

1. if use maven dependency, the compiler say that's ok! because i have jetifier!
2. if use source dependency, the compiler report problem, some function in the library `(eg. void doSomeThing(andorid.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity activity))`, but in the application module i only have `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`, even i can use android.enableJetifier=false in the library module to resolve other compile problem

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You either port the library yourself to androidx and make it as a local dependency instead or use support lib.